# Storing polish character as variable in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am creating a simple registration form, in which you must type your nickname into textarea. The problem occurs when user uses polish characters (ś,ż,ć etc.). When I try to display the whole string by echo it looks just how it should, but when I try to display only one character then it shows this weird �  symbol.

```
function ech($nam)
{
    echo $nam;
    echo "</br>";
    echo $nam[1];
}

$te = $_POST['sth']; //$te equals "śżć" now
ech($te);
```

Output:

śżć

�

Comment: @hanshenrik What do you mean by 'fetching the first character'? I am getting the whole string using post method and then i access it with [].

Comment: It is written in the code sample echo "$nam[1];", I thought it is enough.

Comment: weird, i somehow missed it? sorry, retracted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an offset for a character of a string like `$nam[1]` actually only returns a single byte, but the characters are multiple bytes. use multibyte-safe string functions like `mb_substr($nam, 0, 1)`

- php strings are byte arrays (in contrast to, for example, JavaScript, where they are utf16 character arrays), in UTF-8 the string "ś" contains 2 bytes, doing strlen("ś") gives you 2, doing bin2hex("ś") gives you "c59b", and when you do $str[0] you are only fetching the first byte of the 2 bytes that makes up ś, which on it's own happens to mean nothing, hence you get the � when doing $str[0] (fwiw doing echo $str[0].$str[1] would also work because ś happens to be 2 bytes and you'd manually fetch the first 2 bytes)

Comment: sorry to say, this is bogus. maybe you mean `mb_substr($nam,0,1);`

Comment: You're right. Brain went to sleep for a moment.

Comment: oh, now it makes perfect sense :)

Comment: Thank you Jerry and hanshenrik! I did not know it.